# Filter out one to one relationships

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE Advisors (
    AdvisorID int not null IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName varchar(50) not null,
    LastName  varchar(50) not null,
);

CREATE TABLE Students (
    StudentID int not null IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    AdvisorID int  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Advisors(AdvisorID),
    FirstName varchar(50) not null,
    LastName  varchar(50) not null,
);

INSERT INTO Advisors (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('Joy', 'Frank');
INSERT INTO Advisors (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('Franklin',  'Johnson');
INSERT INTO Advisors (FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('Mary', 'Ronald');

INSERT INTO Students (FirstName, LastName, AdvisorID) VALUES ('Danny', 'Sean', 3);
INSERT INTO Students (FirstName, LastName, AdvisorID) VALUES ('Ashford', 'combs', 1);
INSERT INTO Students (FirstName, LastName, AdvisorID) VALUES ('George', 'Stoute', 3);
INSERT INTO Students (FirstName, LastName, AdvisorID) VALUES ('Ben', 'Johnson', 3);
```

I am trying to write a query that will filter out any advisor with more than one student

My query:

```
SELECT Students.StudentID, Students.FirstName, Students.LastName, Advisors.AdvisorID, Advisors.FirstName,Advisors.LastName
FROM Students
LEFT JOIN Advisors ON Students.AdvisorID = Advisors.AdvisorID
WHERE Students.AdvisorID <= 2
```

I am doing it wrong. My query does filter out the advisors with more than one student because I know which Advisor ID has one student.
I am trying to filter out one too many relationships and have the one too one relationship in the results

Comment: have you tried to write the query ?

Comment: Yes but I am stuck on the WHERE clause and sometimes I end up hardcoding which can lead me to errors

Comment: SELECT   Students.StudentID, Students.FirstName,Students.LastName, Advisors.AdvisorID, Advisors.FirstName,Advisors.LastName
FROM Students
Left JOIN Advisors ON Students.AdvisorID = Advisors.AdvisorID
WHERE Students.AdvisorID <= 2;

Comment: I posted my query but it's incorrect. the result does filter out the advisors with more than one student based on the advisor Id but it is an incorrect query

Comment: [edit] it into your quesiton

Comment: BTW - do you realise that you don't need to repeat the `insert` statements when using `values` - `values` allows multiple rows to be specified.

Comment: @DaleK I know but I just did that for fun and I made the edits to the question

Comment: First, you need to find `Advisor` with only one `Student`. Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: @Squirrel Yes, and if you read my query the advisor with only one student has an advisor id less than 2. But in this case, it is sort of hard coding. think about having a bigger database with more records and for example, an advisor with an id of 5 also has one student. my above query is not going to generate th right results

Comment: @DaleK any idea what should I do

Answer (score 2):

```
select AdvisorID
from students
group by AdvisorID
having count(s.StudentID) <= 1
```

Comment: thanks for the help but it did not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me out, I got the answer to my question

```
SELECT Advisors.AdvisorID,Students.TotalStudentsAssigned, Advisors.FirstName + ' ' + 
Advisors.LastName AS AdvisorName
FROM Advisors 
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT adv.AdvisorID, COUNT(*) AS TotalStudentsAssigned
FROM Advisors adv
LEFT JOIN Students s
    ON adv.AdvisorID = s.AdvisorID
GROUP BY adv.AdvisorID
HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
) Students
ON Advisors.AdvisorID = Students.AdvisorID;
```